# Why writing huge amount of data in a circular buffer takes less time when the buffer is small

Tags: c, circular-buffer

I'm studying a circular buffer in C for Audio purpose

The number of bytes I need to write in one memcpy is 2048 bytes - frame size of 512 float samples.

I test for 32000 write operations i.e. 65536000 bytes ( 32000 * 512 *4 )

- If my circular buffer is 0x1000000 length ( 16777216), it takes 12000 micro seconds (*)
- If my circular buffer is 0x100000 length ( 1048576), it takes 4000 micro seconds (*)

It looks like as if it would take more time when the circular buffer is longer 
... although the total bytes written is the same. What could explain such difference?

I try to find for error in my code or in my interpretation of the results but could not find any explanation.

Maybe I have a stupid mistake somewhere but I could not find it.

I write a small example to illustrate my issue:
**Updated version**

```
//
//  main.c
//  TestMemoryWrite
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>       // DST_NONE, gettimeofday

#define kLengthOfOneSetOfFloatToWrite 512
#define kNumberOfSetToWrite  32000
#if 0
 #define kMainBufferLengthInBytes 0x1000000  // 12000 useconds
#else
 #define kMainBufferLengthInBytes  0x100000  //  3500 useconds
#endif
#define kMainBufferLengthInFloat ( kMainBufferLengthInBytes / sizeof(float) )

float gMainBufferFloat[ kMainBufferLengthInFloat ] = {0}; // 16 777 816 bytes
float gSubArrayToWrite[kLengthOfOneSetOfFloatToWrite] = {0};
// gPtrWrite is our void* pointer in gMainBufferFloat
// Each time we write it will be "advanced" for 512 float equivalent
// When gBufferEnd is reached, gPtrWrite is reinitialized at gBufferStart
void * gPtrWrite = (void*)gMainBufferFloat;
void * gBufferStart = (void*)gMainBufferFloat;
void * gBufferEnd = (void*)gMainBufferFloat + kMainBufferLengthInBytes;

// function providing gPtrWrite value
void *ARWritePtr(void)
{
    // Return current Pointer in gMainBufferFloat
    void * ptrWrite = gPtrWrite;
    // Advance our pointer or reset to the start
    // aSetOfBytesToWrite: 2048
    uint32_t aSetOfBytesToWrite = kLengthOfOneSetOfFloatToWrite *  sizeof(float);
    gPtrWrite += aSetOfBytesToWrite;
    // Shall we reach the end next time
    if ( gPtrWrite >= gBufferEnd  ) {
        // Then reset to start
        gPtrWrite = gBufferStart;
    }
    return ptrWrite;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    // Initialize items to compute elapsed time
    struct timeval  tv1, tv2;
    struct timezone  tz1 = {0, DST_NONE};
    unsigned long tv_sec, tv_usec;

    // Create data for the test
    // Initialize random functions
    srand((int)time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i<kLengthOfOneSetOfFloatToWrite; i++) {
       gSubArrayToWrite[i] = (float)rand()/1000000.0;
    }

    // initialize timing
    gettimeofday( &tv1, &tz1);

    // lengthToWriteInBytes: 512 * 4
    // -> 2048
    uint32_t lengthToWriteInBytes = kLengthOfOneSetOfFloatToWrite * sizeof(float);

    // totalBytesToWrite: 32000 * 512 * 4
    // -> 65536000
    uint32_t totalBytesToWrite = kNumberOfSetToWrite * kLengthOfOneSetOfFloatToWrite * sizeof(float);

    printf("kNumberOfSetToWrite:%u\n", kNumberOfSetToWrite);
    printf("of kLengthOfOneSetOfFloatToWrite:%u\n", kLengthOfOneSetOfFloatToWrite);
    printf("total bytes:%u \n", totalBytesToWrite);
    printf("expected overrides:%u\n", (uint32_t)totalBytesToWrite / kMainBufferLengthInBytes);

    float *framefloat = NULL;
    float *framefloatPrevious = NULL;
    // 32000 loops
    uint32_t countOfResets = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < kNumberOfSetToWrite  ; i++) {
        // get current pointer to write in our buffer
        framefloat = (float*)ARWritePtr();
        // if our pointer is smaller than before, we had a reset
        if (framefloat < framefloatPrevious  && framefloatPrevious ) {
            countOfResets++;
        }
        // copy our 2048 bytes: memcpy(dst, src, length)
        memcpy((void*)framefloat, (void*)gSubArrayToWrite, lengthToWriteInBytes);
        framefloatPrevious = framefloat;
    }

    gettimeofday( &tv2, &tz1);
    tv_sec=tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec;
    tv_usec=tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec;

    printf("\n- %lu Seconds %lu Micro Seconds \n", tv_sec,  tv_usec);
    printf("average Micro Seconds / count framesToWrite:%f\n", (double)tv_usec / (double)kNumberOfSetToWrite);
    printf("total bytes written:%u  count of resets:%u\n\n", totalBytesToWrite, countOfResets );

    return 0;
}
```

Would anyone have an explanation?

(*)Using MacBook Pro 16GB 2,7 GHz Intel Core i7

Comment: Just a guess, but it might be because the smaller cache fits within the processers cache.

Comment: Caching. There are various caches in the operating system - the data caches, and the translation lookaside buffer for example.

Comment: Also, one wouldn't *copy* the buffers around like this, instead you'd produce into the next buffer, or add a next buffer to the list of buffers to consume, or so.

Comment: Indeed. I would write in the ring buffer based on a AudioUnit callback and consume the data for eg. FFT via vDSP computations when reaching say 16384 samples. But , at the end, I would write millions of bytes in the ring buffer. In this case, if the speed can be optimised by a factor 3, I try to understand why and eventually apply it.

Comment: What @AnttiHaapala says.  As the buffers get bigger, the bigger the performance advantage of handling them by address, rather than copying bulk data.  This is especially  true when a lock needs to be held when queueing a buffer - the lock only needs to be held for the time taken to push a pointer, no matter how large the buffer pointed to.

Comment: @ MartinJames Not sure to understand correctly, event if I use directly the content of the buffer, I need to feed it first. No?

Comment: the posted code does not compile!! the compiler outputs many warnings messages and some error messages.  (ubuntu linux 16.04, gcc version 5.4.0)  How do you expect us to perform any analysis on your code when the posted code does not compile?

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdint.h>`  for the definitions of types like: `uint32_t`

Comment: in function: `ARWritePtr( float array[] )` the parameter `array[]` is not used, so why pass it to the function?

Comment: the macro: `DST_NONE` is not declared in the posted code

Comment: the function: `srand()` expects a parameter of type: `unsigned int`, not `int`

Comment: this expression: `(float)rand()/1000000.0;` is taking a `int`/ dividing it by a `double`, then casting the result to `float`.   Suggest using: `(float)rand()/1000000.0F;

Comment: regarding: `unsigned long tv_sec, tv_usec;`  these fields are being set from a `long int` value, so either cast them accordingly or (prefered) use: ` long tv_sec, tv_usec;

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 2) place appropriate horizontal spacing, after semicolor, after comma, inside parens, around C operators.   The compiler doesn't care, but it really helps us humans to read/understand the code

Comment: there are two valid signatures for the `main()` function.  `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, const char *argv[] )`  When the parameters are not going to be used, the proper signature is: `int main( void )`

Comment: this statement: `uint32_t totalBytesToWrite = kNumberOfSetToWrite  \
                               * kLengthOfOneSetOfFloatToWrite  \
                               * sizeof(float);` should not have the 'line continuation' marks.  Suggest: `uint32_t totalBytesToWrite = kNumberOfSetToWrite
                               * kLengthOfOneSetOfFloatToWrite
                               * sizeof(float);

Comment: this statement: `printf( "\n- %lu Seconds %lu Micro Seconds \
           average Micro Seconds / count framesToWrite:%f \
           total bytes written:%u  count of resets:%u\n\n" ....
should not have the 'line continuation' marks.  Suggest: `printf("kNumberOfSetToWrite:%u "
           "of kLengthOfOneSetOfFloatToWrite:%u "
           "total bytes:%u "
           "expected overrides:%u\n" ....`  because successive character string literals are concatenated into a single string.

Comment: after cleaning up all the compiler problems, this line: `memcpy(framefloat, gSubArrayToWrite, lengthToWriteInBytes);` causes a seg fault event because the variable: `framefloat` contains 0

Comment: on the second iteration of the `for()` loop at the end of `main()`, this line: `memcpy(framefloat, gSubArrayToWrite, lengthToWriteInBytes);` is writing past the end of the destination array.  This results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: @ user3629249 Sorry that you have so many issues in Linux with GCC 5.4.0, I'm using Xcode 8.3.3 on macOS 10.12.6 Sierra which uses the compiler LLVM 8.1  ARCHS = x86_64 and have no warning.

Comment: DST_NONE on macOS is declared in sys/time.h and uint32_t is declared via <stdlib.h>

Comment: I do not have any errors that you mentioned. I suppose that it might be related to differences in OS/compilers or architecture used.

Comment: For the issue related in the `for` loop,  the buffer size being a whole multiple of `lengthToWritesInBytes`  prevents any issue and `ARWritePtr` prevents the issue for the next read (the whole multiple is tested in the original project but not here)

Comment: Hi, I was able to test on a Linux machine compiling with GCC 6.2, We had some framework issues related to the includes as mentioned, but then the execution did run just fine.